# Вопрос связанный с методом Multiple

Tags: java, матрицы

Можете помочь написать метод Multiple который создает две матрицы и умножает их.

```
 public static Matrix fillByKeyboard() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows:");
        int rowCount = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Columns:");
        int colCount = scan.nextInt();
        try {
            Matrix m = new Matrix(rowCount, colCount);
            System.out.println("Enter Matrix Data:");
            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++) {
                    int value = scan.nextInt();
                     m.put(i, j, value);
                }
            }
            return m;

        } catch (MatrixIndexException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
        return null;

    }

    public static void MatrixMultiple(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter The Number of Rows");
        int rowCount = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter The Number of Columns");
        int colCount = scan.nextInt();

    }
}
```